# Creating and installing python package from git repo

Tags: python, git, pip, package

I'm trying to create a python package with one module after which I want to upload it to my repo on github and subsequently install it from that repo using the command line

`pip install git+https://github.com/my_username/my_repo`.

When I try this I get this message

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-ipnr8pws-build/`

I then tried

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/my_username/my_repo#egg=my_repo
```

Which seemed to sort of work as the file shows up in my src folder however it creates a file in the src folder that holds the python project which in turn holds the python package and module. This means that pip can't find the setup.py in the first directory and I need to physically go into the src folder and delete that first folder and rearrange everything so that the setup.py folder is in the first directory instead of the second. At this point it installs and I can import it in a python shell (I still can't get the module to run from the imported package but that's a different problem probably)

My question thus is, what is the best procedure for installing a python package from git? Is there a way that I can do it without having to go into my src folder to rearrange things?

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='sysinfo_v2',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='Hugh O\'Brien,',
    author_email='xxx@ucdconnect.ie',
    packages=['sysinfo_v2'],
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='Get platform info',
)
```

Here's setup.py in case that's of any use

Comment: That's the correct way to install using `pip` from a git url. What do you see if you run `python setup.py egg_info` in a checked out project directory?

Comment: @match I ran this on a cloned repo for pandas and it created an egg_info file and a manifest file and a bunch of other things. I then tried to run the same command on the cloned repo of my own project and it told me that egg_info was an invalid command

Comment: @match just tried running `pip install Distribute` and the install failed with the following message `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oet1oon2/Distribute/`

Comment: Might not help, but you could try ensuring the latest pip and setuptools are installed: `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`

Comment: @match Yes, already checked that. All up to date

Comment: Just noticed you're using `distuitls`, which is deprecated. Try using `from setuptools import setup` in `setup.py` instead.

Comment: @match changed that, deleted the local src file for my project and reinstalled from the github repo. The same thing happened, an egg folder was created that held my project folder and thus I needed to rearrange everything so that it could find the setup.py. Should I not keep the package in a its own project folder?

Comment: Running `setup.py egg_info` was just to look for errors. I think that after changing to `setuptools` and pushing the updated code to github, the `pip install` should just work.

Comment: @match `python setup.py egg_info` now works on my project as well after that change

Comment: @match it seems to be working now although I've got an error that it can't find my package but I presume I've just screwed up in my naming. Thanks for your help, I'll go away and do some research on egg_info now.

Comment: It would help if you would either provide the link to the mentioned github repo or create an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem.